# Remove country from address line via AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email

I want to populate the email to pull in %%Location%% as just the town name. The data extension being used has a column for address that currently pulls it in as 'town, country' e.g. "Brighton, United Kingdom" - I want to use AMPscript to show the value as just the town name, e.g. "Brighton".

Is there an easy way to use AMPscript to do this within the email text block? We are not able to separate address into two columns (e.g. town, country) in the DE at this current time.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by using a [Substring](https://ampscript.guide/substring/) function to cut the remaining string after the comma:

> This function returns a portion of the specified string starting at a
> certain character position and no longer than the specified length. If
> the specified character position is more than the length of the
> specified string, the function returns an empty string. If you do not
> specify a value for the third parameter, the function will return the
> remainder of the string.

So in your case, replace the %%Location%% personalization string with below:

```
%%=v(Substring(Location,1, Subtract(IndexOf(Location,", "),1)))=%%
```

Source: https://ampscript.guide/substring/

Comment: Another option I have seen used, but I usually use substring like above myself, is to utilize `BuildRowsetFromString()`. For example: `var @rs = BuildRowsetFromString(@Location, ",")  var @town = Field(Row(@rs,1),1) `  Which would give you a rowset built from that string, delimited by the comma. You then take the first value, which is the town in the rowset by using the Field and Row commands.